# PHP wordwrap array to Javascript returns in error

Tags: javascript, php

I'm getting a console error when running the follow code:

```
<?php
$str = "Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.";
$str = wordwrap($str,30,'\n');
?>

document.write('test' + '\n');
document.write( '<?php echo $str;?>' + '\n' );

</script>
```

Console error: **Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list**.

Where is the problem?

Comment: Well what does the resulting JavaScript look like?

Comment: Quote in the text breaks your code, learn what is __escaping__.

Comment: @u_mulder I need to escaping both php and js?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @u_mulder noted you must escape quote sign `'` as:

```
<?php
    $str = "Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.";
    $str = str_replace("'", "\'", wordwrap($str,30,'\n'));
?>
<script>
    document.write('test' + '\n');
    document.write( '<?php echo $str;?>' + '\n' );
</script>
```

Look [PHP fiddle](https://phpize.online/?phpses=e739c25f984446cefe774d9b11895e6f&sqlses=null&php_version=php7&sql_version=mysql80)